# NSMutableArray returns null when set in previous viewController

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I am setting an array of a viewController in previous viewController, but it returns null in the viewController. I have also set its properties.

Previous viewController:

```
controller.arrGUID = arr;
```

ViewController

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *arrGUID;  //synthesized as well.
```

Using arrGUID in viewController returns null.

Comment: pass your array after allocinit nibname and before pushview.. please write some code so i will help you.

Comment: I am doing the same what you have written.

Answer (score 0):

```
NextViewController *controller = [[NextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.arrGUID = arr;// where arr is previous controller array.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

also nslog in nextviewcontroller's viewdidload method.

it will help you.

Comment: den chek arr. maybe it has nullvalue init.

Comment: try this.  controller.arrGUID = [arr copy];

Answer (score 0):

I think You have reatin problem

try this

```
 controller.arrGUID = [arr retain];
```